# How to retrieve an output value from a stored procedure via DAO pass-through query

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, stored-procedures, return-value, dao

I am converting an ADP to an ACCDB (tables/views linked to SQL Server), and had pretty good luck with DAO pass-through queries. The one area where I'm stuck is in retrieving an OUTPUT parameter from a stored procedure.

The SP has the following parameters

```
(@IType int, @RetVal bit OUTPUT)
```

and, simply speaking, the following processing logic

```
IF @IType = 1
    SET @RetVal = (SELECT ... 
. . .
```

No records are returned. All that is needed by the Access VBA procedure is the RetVal.

I have searched the web, and the solutions tend to be geared toward writing the value to a table, or using ADODB.

I really want to avoid modifying the stored proc, as the change would have to be propagated to multiple databases.

Also, it would be nice to stick with DAO pass-throughs since I have already started down that path.

Is there any way of achieving this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can create a pass-through query that uses an *anonymous code block* to retrieve the OUTPUT parameter. For the stored procedure

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[IsOne] 
    @IType INT = 0, 
    @RetVal BIT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    IF @IType = 1
        SET @RetVal = 1;
    ELSE
        SET @RetVal = 0;
END
```

you can use VBA code like this:

```vbs
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Sub ptqTest()
    Dim cdb As DAO.Database
    Set cdb = CurrentDb
    Dim ptq As DAO.QueryDef
    Set ptq = cdb.CreateQueryDef("")  ' temporary pass-through query
    ptq.Connect = "ODBC;DSN=SQLmyDb"
    ptq.ReturnsRecords = True
    ptq.SQL = _
            "DECLARE @rv BIT;" & _
            "EXEC dbo.IsOne @IType = 3, @RetVal = @rv OUTPUT;" & _
            "SELECT @rv;"
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Set rs = ptq.OpenRecordset
    ' BIT value 0 will map to False in this case
    Debug.Print "stored procedure returned " & rs(0)  
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set ptq = Nothing
    Set cdb = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: This absolutely did the trick!  I think I had blinders on to any solution that returned a recordset. Now I see that we would be producing an on-request recordset without touching the SP.  Very clever.  I very much appreciate the quick response and concise example.

Comment: I will admit that I found at least two places on the web where it was claimed that this couldn't be done with DAO. Not true, folks!

Comment: It works a treat - just beware of the "max records" parameter. It restricts the number of records but not just (as I thought) what is returned to the application, BUT the number of records being actioned during Selects or similar in the Proc being run.